# The method return the varible without modifying it

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

i have a problem with my code in Swift 
the method verifyInput should return false when there's an error
but it always return true no matter what + when there's an error it print "error" but its just return true

please help

```
@IBAction func register(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let check = verifyInput(email :email.text! ,password: password.text!)
    if(check==true){

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToAmazon", sender: nil)

    } else if(check==false) {

        self.message.text = "Sorry! there's an error"
    }


}

func verifyInput(email: String, password: String) -> Bool {

    var check = true
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("error")
            check = false
        } else if(error==nil){
            check = true
            print("registered!")
        }

    }

   return check
}
```

Comment: Do some research on asynchronous API calls.

Comment: reading this might help you to understand more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748175/asynchronous-vs-synchronous-execution-what-does-it-really-mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `verifyInput` is being called synchronously from `register` but within it is an asynchronous call to `Auth.auth().createUser` with a completion block.

The `check` result is being returned before the asynchronous call ever completes.  You need to change your method to be asynchronous as well.

Something vaguely like this is what you want:

```
@IBAction func register(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if let email = email.text, let password = password.text {
        verifyInput(email: email, password: password) { (check) in

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // only run UI code on the main thread
                if(check){
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToAmazon", sender: nil)
                } else {
                    self.message.text = "Sorry! there's an error"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func verifyInput(email: String, password: String, escaping completion:@escaping (Bool)->Void) {

    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("error")
            completion(false)
        } else if(error==nil){
            print("registered!")
            completion(true)
        }
    }
}
```